# Arial font not working in browsers on Android

Tags: android, css, font-family

I have a smartphone with Android 11 and use the following CSS code on a website

```
body{
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I tried different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Brave) but the font isn't shown in Arial but some other sans-serif font.

While Arial is said to be "one of the safest web fonts, and it is available on all major operating systems." it seems not to be available on my Android device (I also checked on a different device, wasn't available either).

Here also a screenshot where the "t" (like in "sit") in the example shows clearly that Arial isn't used.

[image: Screenshot of the website w3schools.com showing the article on websafe fonts with an example text about Arial not set in Arial]

How comes Arial is not available on Android?

Comment: Arial is a commercial font, and Android is an open source operating system. I would expect that the decision for licensing Arial would be up to device manufacturers, and so whether it exists may vary by manufacturer.

Comment: There are many fonts that are metric-compatible with Arial, so even if the result isn't pixel-perfect, the layout will be the same regardless if it's Arial or a substitute. If you really need to be sure to have the same font literally everywhere, use a webfont.